# Using curly brackets to escape variable from letters vs. speed

Tags: shell, sed

In linux shell, usual way to escape variable from word / letter seems to be:

```
sed -n ${x}p

echo "${x}th number"
```

As far as I understand, curly brackets are for variable expansion.
Question I have is, is there cleaner way to escape variables,
since there might be a concern escaping it this way might make the script slower, since we are using the expansion, even though we don't need it (*we just need to delimit the variable and other letters.*).

So far I have chosen different approaches to go around this.
e.g.

```
.. | head -n $x | tail -n 1
.. | sed -n "$x p" <[this seems strange]
```

*edit*: I have found an alternative approach using

```
.. | sed -n $(echo $n)p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the bash manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with
>   more than one digit, **or when parameter is followed by a character that
>   is not to be interpreted as part of its name**.

So I would say the answer is, no. And I can't imagine any work-arounds, while perhaps a fun exercise, wouldn't be much slower than just using the braces.

More importantly, have you even tried to measure the penalty of using `${x}` over `$x`? If so, please include it in your question because I have never heard expressed ever any "concern escaping it this way might make the script slower".

Finally, I would suggest that if you're worried about performance to the point of worrying about using braces, you probably want to be doing the work in a language other than shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I decided to go with the head / tail combination as of now. Regarding speed, in the past, when using the curly brackets expansion for substitution I encountered some errors and also huge speed losses. - Script batches may sometimes need speed optimization too.

Answer (score 1):

I've observed a significant delta in speed between brace enclosed variables and non brace enclosed variables **with bash**. Searching about that delta, i found this question. As i see that @jas asks for a measure of the penalty, here's my tests and the results on a **Debian Buster** ​10.7 64 Bits x86_64 at a quiet time (one user logged, standard background process from fresh install) with bash 5.0.3 stable, CPU intel 4670K non OC :

`bash_var.sh`, braces enclosed variables evaluated 1 million times for a square signal.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
braces_perf_test() {
  local LOCALV_MYSTRVAR="has a value"
  local LOCALV_COUNT=0
  while [ "${LOCALV_COUNT}" -lt 1000000 ] ; do
    if [ "${LOCALV_MYSTRVAR}" = "has a value" ] ; then
      LOCALV_MYFLAG=$(( 1 - ${LOCALV_MYFLAG:-0} ));
    fi
    LOCALV_COUNT=$(( ${LOCALV_COUNT} + 1 ));
  done
}
braces_perf_test;
```

```
$ time /bin/bash bash_var.sh

real    0m11.246s
user    0m11.203s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Tests run 10 times and i keep the result nearest to the average, variation +/-100ms.

`bash_var2.sh`, **non** braces enclosed variables evaluated 1 million times for a square signal.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
braces_perf_test() {
  local LOCALV_MYSTRVAR="has a value"
  local LOCALV_COUNT=0
  while [ "$LOCALV_COUNT" -lt 1000000 ] ; do
    if [ "$LOCALV_MYSTRVAR" = "has a value" ] ; then
      LOCALV_MYFLAG=$(( 1 - ${LOCALV_MYFLAG:-0} ));
    fi
    LOCALV_COUNT=$(( $LOCALV_COUNT + 1 ));
  done
}
braces_perf_test;
```

```
$ time /bin/bash bash_var2.sh

real    0m10.042s
user    0m9.969s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Tests run 10 times and i keep the result nearest to the average, variation +/-100ms.

Same tests forced trough a POSIX shell, dash :

```
$ time /bin/dash bash_var.sh

real    0m2.704s
user    0m2.672s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time /bin/dash bash_var2.sh

real    0m2.674s
user    0m2.656s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Tests run 10 times and i keep the result nearest to the average, variation +/-25ms.

To avoid I/O disruption, tests without while subshell involved by using recursion, limited to 5000 levels :

`bash_var_recurse.sh`, braces enclosed variables evaluated 5000 times for a square signal.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
braces_perf_test_recurse() {
    if [ "${LOCALV_MYSTRVAR}" = "has a value" ] ; then
      LOCALV_MYFLAG=$(( 1 - ${LOCALV_MYFLAG:-0} ));
    fi
    LOCALV_COUNT=$(( ${LOCALV_COUNT} + 1 ));
    [ "${LOCALV_COUNT}" -lt 5000 ] && braces_perf_test_recurse;
}
braces_perf_test() {
  local LOCALV_MYSTRVAR="has a value"
  local LOCALV_COUNT=0
  braces_perf_test_recurse;
}
braces_perf_test;
```

```
$ time /bin/bash bash_var_recurse.sh

real    0m6.555s
user    0m6.500s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Tests run 10 times and i keep the result nearest to the average, variation +/-25ms.

`bash_var2_recurse.sh`, **non** braces enclosed variables evaluated 5000 times for a square signal.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
braces_perf_test_recurse() {
    if [ "$LOCALV_MYSTRVAR" = "has a value" ] ; then
      LOCALV_MYFLAG=$(( 1 - ${LOCALV_MYFLAG:-0} ));
    fi
    LOCALV_COUNT=$(( $LOCALV_COUNT + 1 ));
    [ "$LOCALV_COUNT" -lt 5000 ] && braces_perf_test_recurse;
}
braces_perf_test() {
  local LOCALV_MYSTRVAR="has a value"
  local LOCALV_COUNT=0
  braces_perf_test_recurse
}
braces_perf_test;
```

```
$ time /bin/bash bash_var2_recurse.sh

real    0m6.544s
user    0m6.438s
sys     0m0.047s
```

Tests run 10 times and i keep the result nearest to the average, variation +/-25ms.

As @Mark reed raises the point in the comments, the counter increment can be evaluated directly with `((LOCALV_COUNT++));`, non POSIX compatible but the resulting tests show a significant gain for bash on that too :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
braces_perf_test() {
  local LOCALV_MYSTRVAR="has a value"
  local LOCALV_COUNT=0
  while [ "$LOCALV_COUNT" -lt 1000000 ] ; do
    if [ "$LOCALV_MYSTRVAR" = "has a value" ] ; then
      LOCALV_MYFLAG=$(( 1 - ${LOCALV_MYFLAG:-0} ));
    fi
    ((LOCALV_COUNT++));
  done
}
braces_perf_test;
```

```
$ time /bin/bash bash_var2_math.sh

real    0m9.325s
user    0m9.145s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Tests run 10 times and i keep the result nearest to the average, variation +/-75ms.

My personal conclusion : Braces enclosed variables seems about 10% slower in the context of a subshell with bash, add no or very little effect on a POSIX shell. Bash recursion is exponentially costly above about 100 levels of recursions. Braces enclosed variables delta versus non braces enclosed with bash recursion seems not significant.  Thus : Braces enclose your variables with no worries, reliability first speed second.